# SSL offloading redirect to https

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl, f5

How do you tell a https terminating load balancer to redirect from a http request to a https request?

I have a .net app which will redirect visitors to SSL if they visit certain pages.

Answer (score 0):

You just send a normal redirect to the client.

The response will be the sent out using the original http request and the new https request will terminate SSL at the load balancer as per normal.